# Delineating a Read File

Tags: python, file-handling

Not really too sure how to word this question, therefore if you don't particularly understand it then I can try again.

I have a file called *example.txt* and I'd like to import this into my Python program. Here I will do some calculations with what it contains and other things that are irrelevant.

Instead of me importing this file, going through it line-by-line and extracting the information I want.. can Python do it instead? As in, if I structure the *.txt* correctly (whether it be key / value pairs seperated by an equals on each line), is there a current Python 'way' where it can handle it all and I work with that?

Comment: Since `import` is a reserved word -- with very specific meaning -- in Python, please change the title of your question. You appear to be asking something about "reading" a file.  Please update your question to clarify the title and reflect what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split("=")
        do_something(key,value)
```

looks like a starting point if I understand you correctly. You need Python 2.6 or 3.x for this.

Another place to look is the `csv` module that can parse comma-separated value files - and you can tell it to use `=` as a separator instead. This will abstract away some of the "manual work" in that previous example - but it seems your example doesn't especially need that kind of abstraction.

Another idea:

```
with open("example.txt") as f:
    d = dict([line.strip().split("=") for line in f])
```

Now that's concise and pythonic :)

Comment: Ah, interesting. Yes I think that will do the job. I'm trying to seperate these key / value pairs however some of the values are seperated by commas... but I'll be able to handle that! Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: I added a `.strip()` method call to get rid of newlines - and another way to do everything in one line via a list comprehension.

Comment: Fantastic! I was just playing around with a couple of String manipulations when I seen your comment! Cheers!

Comment: You might be happier with `line.strip().partition('=')`.  It can handle a value that has an '=' in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open("file")
    key, value = line.strip().split("=")
    key=key.strip() 
    value=value.strip() 
    do_something(key,value)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also another method - you can create a valid python file (let it be a list, dict definition or whatever else), read its content using

```
f = open('file.txt', r)
content = f.read() #assuming file isn't too long
```

And then just parse it:

```
parsedContent = eval(content)
```

You can pass any environment to eval (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)), so it might not have access to your globals and locals. This is *evil* and wrong, but in small program that won't be distributed and won't get 'file.txt' from network or from so called *malicious user* - you can use it.